# Can anyone provide a detailed explanation about the rgbx8888 format?

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb

I would like to extract pixel data from a frame which is saved in rgbx8888 using c++. Can someone provide a detailed description of the format and any extra information which will help me analyse the image.

Comment: Assuming each byte is a pixel component and the pixel is stored in a 32-bit integer, you can use `(x >> (c * 8) & 0xFF)` to extract component c from pixel x.

Comment: I'd suspect it's an equivalent to [RGB + Alpha channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space). `8888` meaning each color and alpha value stored in one byte (all in all a 32-bit integer).

Comment: Images in C or C-API are usually interleaved, where RGBA channels are close together. In some others like matlab, it's not, and data is ordered as R-frame, G-frame, B-frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each pixel consists of four 8-bit bytes. The first three are 8-bit primary colour components - **R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue, in that order, on a linear scale from 0 (none) to 255 (saturated). The fourth (**X**) is unused, to align each pixel on a 4-byte boundary.